# Is __extension__ keyword portable among all compilers?

Tags: c, keyword, portability

Is `__extension__` keyword portable among all compilers ?
I looked into it in the gcc manual, but they did not mentioned if this keyword is portable. If some know, I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

no. Anything not covered by the C standard is not portable. And that is the reason why we need to write such a horrible code if we want (or have to) to use compiler specific extensions pragmas or attributes.

```
#if  defined ( __GNUC__ )
#ifndef __weak
#define __weak   __attribute__((weak))
#endif /* __weak */
#ifndef __packed
#define __packed __attribute__((__packed__))
#endif /* __packed */
#endif /* __GNUC__ */


/* In HS mode and when the DMA is used, all variables and data structures dealing
   with the DMA during the transaction process should be 4-bytes aligned */

#if defined ( __GNUC__ ) && !defined (__CC_ARM) /* GNU Compiler */
#ifndef __ALIGN_END
#define __ALIGN_END    __attribute__ ((aligned (4U)))
#endif /* __ALIGN_END */
#ifndef __ALIGN_BEGIN
#define __ALIGN_BEGIN
#endif /* __ALIGN_BEGIN */
#else
#ifndef __ALIGN_END
#define __ALIGN_END
#endif /* __ALIGN_END */
#ifndef __ALIGN_BEGIN
#if defined   (__CC_ARM)      /* ARM Compiler */
#define __ALIGN_BEGIN    __align(4U)
#elif defined (__ICCARM__)    /* IAR Compiler */
#define __ALIGN_BEGIN
#endif /* __CC_ARM */
#endif /* __ALIGN_BEGIN */
#endif /* __GNUC__ */
```

Comment: To  be fair, the code you posted seems to be for a device driver doing DMA.  That will be highly implementation-dependent code, and likely isn't strictly compliant C as strictly-compliant C likely couldn't work for what the code is trying to do.